# How do I make the trigger run after all the data is inserted into the batch class?

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to use Apex Batch class to put 10,000 pieces of data into an object called A and use After Insert trigger to update the weight field value of 10,000 pieces of data to 100 if the largest number of weight fields is 100.

But now, if Batch size is 500, the number with the largest weight field value out of 500 data is applied to 500 data.

Of the following 500 data, the number with the largest weight field value applies to 500 data.

For example, if the weight field for the largest number of the first 500 data is 50,

Weight field value for data 1-50: 50

If the weight field for the largest number of the following 500 data is 100,

Weight field value for data 51-100: 100

I'm going to say that if the data is 10,000, the weight field is the largest number out of 10,000 data. I want to update the weight field value of all data.

How shall I do it? Here's the code for the trigger I wrote.

```java
trigger myObjectTrigger on myObject_status__c (after insert) {
    List<myObject_status__c> objectStatusList = [SELECT Id, Weight FROM myObject_status__c WHERE Id IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet() ORDER BY Weight DESC];

    Decimal maxWeight = [SELECT Id, Weight FROM myObject_status__c ORDER BY Weight DESC Limit 1].weight;

    for(Integer i=0; i < objectStatusList(); i++){
        objectStatusList[i].Weight = maxWeight;
    }
 
    update objectStatusList;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A trigger is not the correct approach here

While the trigger you have so far is close to working *in theory*, you'll find yourself querying many rows and performing DML updates on many records. With 10,000 records, you would be guaranteed to go over the governor limits for query rows and DML rows (and likely SOQL queries as well. 10k records = 50 chunks of 200 records. 2 queries per chunk puts you right at the 100 query limit).

This approach would run into governor limits. Even working with 2,200 records in this manner would run into governor limits because you'd need to query *and potentially update* all of the previous records that you've already processed (in the case that the current trigger chunk has a larger weight than any previous chunk).

- 2.2k records = 11 chunks of 200 records (i.e. your trigger will run 11 times in the transaction)
- worst case is that you need to update all previous records
- 200 + 400 + ... + 1,800 + 2,000 = 11,000 DML rows
- DML row governor limit is 10,000 (and this is a hard limit)

### There is something you could do to avoid that worst case

If you could guarantee that the largest weight is always the first record that would be inserted (and you only ever insert data into this object once), then your trigger code would no longer need to assume that worst case and you could get away with simply updating the records in each chunk.

However, at that point (you have figured out what the largest weight is and ensure it is inserted first), you would have all the information you need to set the maximum weight *before you perform the DML in your batch class*. The trigger becomes obviated (you don't need it any more).

### Conclusion: Just do the work in your batch class (or another batch class that you chain in the `finish()` method)

Batch classes are much better suited for tasks of this type. That is, things of a "go through all of the records of an SObject" nature.

With a trigger, you can only easily see and operate on the current "chunk" of 200 records. You generally cannot know what the maximum will be until you process all of the records. Determining when the final trigger chunk is being run is also generally something you can't do from within the trigger itself.

With batch apex, you have a chance to gather information about the entire set of records in the `start()` method. Failing that, you can guarantee that another piece of code is run after all of the batch chunks have run via the `finish()` method.

I'd imagine such a batch class to look like this

```java
public class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context){
        // First, a query to find the max value
        // Runs a single time, and queries a single row
        List<MyObject__c> maxRecordList = [SELECT Target_Field__c FROM MyObject__c ORDER BY Target_Field__c DESC LIMIT 1];

        // To avoid needing a stateful batch class while still being able to access this
        //   data in the independent calls to execute(), insert a special SObject record.
        // Having a field you can use to mark this record as being special helps in two ways:
        //   - Making it easy to find and use in the execute() method
        //   - Making it easy to find and delete in the finish() method
        insert new OtherObject__c(
            // Ternary just in case there are no records to draw data from
            Weight__c = maxRecordList.isEmpty() ? 0 : maxRecordList[0].Target_Field__c,
            Special_Record__c = true
        );

        return Database.getQueryLocator(someQueryHere);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> lstScope) {
        // Find the special record
        // ORDER BY just in case you forgot to clean up previous records
        OtherObject__c specialRec = [SELECT Weight__c FROM OtherObject__c WHERE Special_Record__c = true ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];

        List<OtherObject__c> recordsToInsert = new List<OtherObject__c>();

        for(MyObject__c mySObj :(List<MyObject__c>)lstScope){
            recordsToInsert.add(new OtherObject__c(
                Weight__c = specialRec.Weight__c,
                Other_Field__c = 'other value'
            );
        }

        insert recordsToInsert;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context){
        // clean up after yourself
        delete [SELECT Id FROM OtherObject__c WHERE Special_Record__c = true];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
We will proceed with reference to the information.
It was a great help to me.